# Android-Load images into Listview

Tags: android, web-services, listview

I have `ListView` and `Fragment`. there I'm having web  images which are from web service, and put those images into `ListView`. All the time when I log into my application, images initializing from web service and my app become slow.Below are the steps I want to do and overcome delay of my application.

**1.** When user first time comes to application all the images downloading from web service and put those  images inside phone.

**2.** Second time user log into app, images getting fetch from phone.

How can I achieve it? please help me.

Comment: Look at [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Answer (score 1):

Try Picasso library, might solve your issue.
http://square.github.io/picasso/

Picasso.with(context).load("https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5w9Z.jpg").into(imageView);